# NX/SSH remote access with Remmina

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, ssh, openssh, freenx

After many days and a lot of frustration, I managed to get freenx to work on my home server. I can connect to it with nomachine's linux client, but I want to use Remmina for this purpose. The problem is that I don't exactly know how to connect to a NX-server with the program.

In the connection dialog, I've chosen SSH as the protocol, and I've correctly added the IP and port. Under "SSH Authentication" I've added my user name on the server, and I choose "identity file" and selected the ssh-key I generated (which works with nxclient). (When am I supposed to provide my password for the user on the server?)

When I try to connect I get the message:

> SSH public key authentication failed: Public key file doesn't exist

Why do I get this message? How shall I proceed correctly to get the authentication working?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I hope you'll find a solution but if not, why not use nxserver/client from NoMachine, it's free (not OS, but free), and it works great.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remmina actually has a separate plugin for connecting to NX servers. You can get it by installing the `remmina-plugin-nx` package. Once you install that, you will have NX available in the Remmina connection dialog.

You may also want to try a separate program called `qtnx`. It's also available in the Software Center. It's a little simpler and seems to work better for me when connecting to NX servers.

Comment: `remmina-plugin-nx` is no longer in the Ubuntu repos, looks like some known issues: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/remmina/+bug/1163652